# Calling validate function before submiting the form using ngNativeValidate

Tags: html, angular, validation, angular2-form-validation

I am trying to call the validate(ngNativeValidate) function on click of button.

My form look like:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEndpoint(myForm.value);" ngNativeValidate>
        <section class="form-block">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="myData.name" [hidden]="true">
            </div>
            </section>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="testEndpoint(myForm.value);">TEST CONNECTION</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableSubmit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
```

Validation works as expected for `SUBMIT` button. I want the same behavior even for `TEST CONNECTION` button. but don't want to submit the form. How I can do it? I think there will be some way to just call the validator function on-click event. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! in advance.

`testEndpoint` is a backend call function.

Comment: (keydown)="testEndpoint(myForm.value);" so keydown event you can check the connection one way

Answer (score 0):

In reactive forms you can use the 'valid' and 'touched' properties of the form to display feedback to the user if what you are trying to do with 'Test connection' button is to check user inputs.

Therefore, you could skip the 'test connection' button and directly output the following span if the form is invalid and the button submit disabled:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableSubmit">SUBMIT</button>
<span *ngIf="!myForm.valid && myForm.touched" class="help-block">Please enter valid data!</span>
```

Comment: Indeed this is one way, which is available everywhere on internet. But while form submit I do not want to write any `span` code. In default behavior, the focus goto exactly at the same place of problem. I want exactly that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a solution: [Trigger Input Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759005/how-to-trigger-angular-2-input-validation-manually)

So, follow this link, you can try this: `form.controls['myControl'].updateValueAndValidity();`.

You can "validate" the complete form, too. Like: `this.myForm.markAllAsTouched();`

Have fun!

Greetings, Florian