# Angular: Trigger a form control validation on change of another form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

Please refer the project in a stackblitz
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qapfbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

As can be seen, I have reactive form with controls as `firstNumber`, `secondNumber` and `thirdNumber`. I need to have validation for form control `thirdNumber` such that its value should not be greater than the value of the form control which is having minimum value among `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`.

The custom validator `validateThirdNumber` which is there in the component works fine whenever form control `thirdNumber` changes, but I need 
fire its validation on changes of form controls `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` too as the validation logic can change on changes of form controls
`firstNumber` and `secondNumber`.

For that purpose, I have added an event on change of form controls `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` where I am marking the form control `thirdNumber` as `touched` but its validation did not seem to be triggered.

So, how to fire the validation for form control `thirdNumber` on changes of form controls `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`?

Also, why is `this.myFormGroup` is undefined some times in custom validator (refer logs in `app.componen.ts` at `line:22`) even after binding `this` to its form control declaration and `this.myFormGroup` is defined in the `constructor`?

Comment: here is the updated demo  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teofun. you can use `updateValueAndValidity()`  function .check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759005/how-to-trigger-angular-2-input-validation-manually.

Answer (score 1):

the best choice for you is to create your own custom global validator.

```
class ValidateThirdNumber {
    static validate(control: AbstractControl) {
          console.log(control);
        if(control) {
           const firstNumber = control.get('firstNumber').value;
           const secondNumber = control.get('secondNumber').value;
           const thirdnumber = control.get('thirdNumber').value;
        if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
          if (thirdnumber > secondNumber) {
            control.get('thirdNumber').setErrors( {greaterThanSecondNumber: true} );   
          }
        } else if (firstNumber < secondNumber) {
          if (thirdnumber > firstNumber) {
              control.get('thirdNumber').setErrors( {greaterThanFirstNumber: true} ); 
          }
        }
        }
        return null;
        }
}
```

the initialization of form group should be:

```
 this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      firstNumber: [0],
      secondNumber: [0],
      thirdNumber: [0]
    }, {validator: [ValidateThirdNumber.validate] });
```

you don't need the touched attribute any more

```
<span *ngIf="myFormGroup.get('thirdNumber').errors?.greaterThanFirstNumber">
  Third number cannot be greater than First Number
 </span>
    <span *ngIf=" myFormGroup.get('thirdNumber').errors?.greaterThanSecondNumber">
  Third number cannot be greater than Second Number
 </span>
```

also you don't need the `(change)` events remove them

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simpler option if you want to use it. No form control validation used.

```html
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" #formRef="ngForm">
    First number:<input #firstNum type="number" formControlName="firstNumber"><br/>
    Second number:<input #secondNum type="number" formControlName="secondNumber"><br/>
    Third number:<input #thirdNum type="number" formControlName="thirdNumber"><br/>
    <span *ngIf="firstNum && thirdNum && (thirdNum.value > firstNum.value)">
      Third number cannot be greater than First Number
    </span>
    <hr>
    <span *ngIf="secondNum && thirdNum && (thirdNum.value > secondNum.value)">
      Third number cannot be greater than Second Number
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

And delete all validation in your `.ts` file.

If you start creating larger components then the form validation option would be best.